# Disable plugin in spesific page without plugin

Tags: plugins

I use "Resize image after upload" plugin for my customers. Because they are lazy and dont optimize image before upload. But it is not good for sliders. I use Slider revolution. How can I do that when I work with Slider Revolution, this plugin will deactive in slider revolution pages? I think we can do it with URL stucture or another method.

Comment: That might be too late. Does the resize plugin change how the images are stored on disk, or does it resize on the fly when images are used? If it never stored the highest resolution image then you'd need to do more than just disable the plugin on the one page.

Comment: No, I mean disable this plugin in slider revolution page. I think when I upload image in Slider Revolution page, then image will not resize, because plugin is disable

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling the plugin, you should try increasing the container of the slider. It will make the images fit there perfectly.

You can do it by adding these codes to the custom CSS of the Customizer:

```
#x-content-band-3 .x-container.width{
width:100%
}

.rev_slider_wrapper{
height:350px;
} 

.rev_slider{
height:350px;
}
```

Comment: I mean that "resize image after upload" plugin convert images to 1000px, for example. But I need to be minimum 1680px image for slider. If I upload 4000px image, my plugin convert to 1000px this image. But I must disable it in slider revolution page. Because 1000px image size is not enough me.